# Working with React's useContext via Storybook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, storybook, use-context, storybook-addon-specifications

I'm trying to access data in the contextAPI via storybook but I couldn't manage it.
Please, keep in mind that there isn't any issue with the original pages, the context is working properly.

React version: 17.0.2
Storybook version: 6.2.7
Here is the devDep:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.2.7",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.2.7",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.2.7",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.2.7",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.1.7",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.2.7",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "sass": "^1.32.8"
}
```

I've added a decorator for the wrapper in preview.js file of Storybook.

```
addDecorator((storyFn) => <GlobalStore>{storyFn()}</GlobalStore>);
```

Then, in the X.stories.js, I'm trying to call useContext as usual:

```
import { GlobalContext } ...
import { useContext } ...

export const SampleStory = () => {
const { Variable } = useContext(GlobalContext);
```

But I'm am facing this error in the story:

```
Cannot read property 'Variable' of undefined
```

As a solution, I created a new component as a new/separated file and imported it through X.stories.js. This solution works but in this way, I have to create lots of unnecessary files which is useless.

Can you please tell me the correct way for that issue?

Thanks in advance, Cheers,

Comment: You need to initialise your context before you can use it - one path for investigation.